# Ways to write "strength"

Tags: vocabulary, difference

What is the difference in writing strength as 力 or 力量 ?

I have seen it both ways and am not sure of the difference.

Comment: 力量 for "power，force，strength" by itself, 力 used in compounds cf. e。g。小马词典 ：能力 néng lì capability; capable; able; ability; CL:个
压力 yā lì pressure
努力 nǔ lì great effort; to strive; to try hard
势力 shì li power; (ability to) influence
有力 etc。

Comment: So i guess i should have added this but would it be correct to have a tattoo with just  力 for strength ?

Comment: why not？ ＂力＂ still can mean "strength", even though in written or spoken text it occurs as a bound morpheme

Comment: 力气 if you refer to human strength. 力量 is more technical. As for tattoos, I have seen 女力 representing feminism and female power.

Comment: 团结就是力量 tuán jié jiù shì lì liang Unity is strength (revolutionary slogan and popular song of 1943)

Comment: I think 女力 is a bad translation for "women/female power".

Comment: jukuu: female power 女性当家, cf. black power, iciba,jukuu :黑人权力

Comment: Foreigners often mistranslate what should be 势力 into 力量

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say sometimes Chinese choose different words for rhythm.
you can say 很有力量, not 很有力
you can say 大力出奇迹(this sentence used during pool games)

They just sounds good~

Comment: supporting preceding answer, at jukuu find examples with "(议论、论据、话、劝说、前额和嘴巴、等等）很有力" also 很有力 used attributively：。。。是很有力的工具、很有力的反驳、很有力的侧翼、

Answer (score 2):

We say 电力 electric power instead of 电的力量; 马力， horsepower, instead of 马的力量，魄力，guts instead of 魂魄的力量，etc.

We say 有力的反击，effective strike back, instead of 有力量的反击。大力的支持，fully support, instead of 大力量的支持，etc.

we use 力量 as a separate word, e.g, 我们的力量, our strength, 团结的力量， unity,s strengths , 集体的力量，groups power, we don't say 我们的力 or 团结的力。

There is an idiom, 群策群力，power of team work. 
There is a phrase, 团队的力量， power of team work.

From the above, I will say 力 and 力量 mean merely same, the difference is 力 mostly used as part of a phrase while 力量 is used as a separate word.